# Placing a window near the system tray

Tags: cross-platform, menu, gtk, system-tray

I am writing a program that needs to set a window just above/below the traybar for gtk. I have tried using the 2 approaches that failed. One was using the gtk_status_icon_position_menu function and placing the window in the point where the user clicks (in the tray bar). The problem is that these solutions work in gnome(Linux) but not in Windows. In Linux they work because the window manager doesn't seem to allow placement of windows in the tray panel, honoring the closest possible. In Windows this doesn't happen and the window can go "out" of the screen which understandably is not desired.

With this said i went out for a work around. My idea was to set the window in the location of mouse click and get the x and y coordinates of a normal window placement and with it's size check if it would be within the screen boundaries. If it was not make the correction. I have came up with the functions needed but for some reason the gdk_drawable_get_size(window->window ,&WindowWidth, &WindowHeight) and other similar functions only give the correct size value after the second run of the signal function. The result of the first run is just 1 to both size and width. (I have read the issue of X11 not giving correct results, but i think this is not it)

```
event_button = (GdkEventButton *) event;
        if (event_button->button == 1)
        {
            if (active == 0)
            {
                gboolean dummy;
                gint WindowHeight, WindowWidth, WindowPosition[2];
                GdkScreen *screen;
                gint ScreenHeight, ScreenWidth;

                dummy = FALSE;
                gtk_widget_show_all(window);
                gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
                gtk_status_icon_position_menu(menu, &pos[X], &pos[Y], &dummy, statusicon);
                gtk_window_move(GTK_WINDOW(window), pos[X],pos[Y]);

                gdk_drawable_get_size(window->window ,&WindowWidth, &WindowHeight);

                screen = gtk_status_icon_get_screen(statusicon);
                ScreenWidth = gdk_screen_get_width(screen);
                ScreenHeight = gdk_screen_get_height(screen);
                g_print("Screen: %d, %d\nGeometry: %d, %d\n",ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, WindowWidth, window->allocation.height);

                gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry),"");
                active = 1; 
                return TRUE;
            }
```

How can i do what i want in a portable way?

Answer (score 0):

I think `gtk_status_icon_position_menu` should work fine, as i used it for the same purpose.
Are you trying this stuff with X11, What is the actual result you are getting.